# ansible jinja2 concatenate IP addresses

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I would like to cocatenate a group of ips into a string.

**example ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181,etc**

```
{% for host in groups['zookeeper'] %}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have the above code, but can't seem to quite figure out how to concatenate into a string.

searching for **"Jinja2 concatenate"** doesn't give me the info I need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Updated this answer, because I think I misunderstood your question.

If you want to concatenate the IP's of each host with some string, you can work with the [loop controls](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#loop-controls), to check if you're in the last iteration:

```
{% for host in groups['zookeeper'] -%}
   {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
   {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

---

Old answer:

The word you're looking for is [`join`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join):

```
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] | join(", ") }}
```

Comment: I edited the question, because I made a mistake in omitting the needed port number.

Comment: Where does the port come from? In case it is a fixed value or inside another var, simply add it behind the var expression: `{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}:{{ port }}`

Comment: ports are fixed values

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `'extract'` filter for this (provided you use `ansible>=2.1`):

```
{{ groups['zookeeper'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth0', 'ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}
```

More info:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers

Comment: This is now available and definitely an improvement over the other possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

Found a similar solution at https://adamj.eu/tech/2014/10/02/merging-groups-and-hostvars-in-ansible-variables/ .

I did a set_fact using a groups variable as suggested in the post:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fqdn_list: |
          {% set comma = joiner(",") %}
          {% for item in play_hosts -%}
              {{ comma() }}{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
          {%- endfor %}
```

This relies on joiner, which has the advantage of not having to worry about the last loop conditional.  Then with set_fact I can make use of the new string in later tasks.